# Display full content up to a certain level

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there a way to show everything: heading + content, up to a certain level (3 for instance) ? 
i tried C-u 3 hide-sublevel (to hide all level 4) => not ok, as this is hiding content up to level 3 
i tried the VISIBILITY (folded) property, but global cycling visibility still show them.

Any hint ? thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way that is not perfect, but that does the job: 
in the beginning of your org file:
`#+STARTUP: showall`

Then in the blocks you want to hide, add a property: 
`:PROPERTIES:
:VISIBILITY: folded
:END:`

Then use `C-u C-u TAB`

Answer (score 0):

Just call `org-shifttab` (<kbd>S-TAB</kbd>) with a prefix argument.

Comment: well, when i say content, i mean what is under the heading (unfold the level3 item). So your command does not show what is inside, unless i don't undestand it. fir instance: http://pastebin.com/MceicVN5

Comment: What could also be acceptable for me is to have a way to tell an item to not unfold, when going in showall visibility state.

Comment: Yes, with `C-u 3 S-TAB`, level 4 items will be hidden.

Comment: thanks for your help, but either you don't understand my question, or i have a wrong setting on my side. Let me give a clear example: Here is the input file: http://pastebin.com/qFGFRUjY . applying `C-u 3 S-TAB` gives: http://pastebin.com/1TysXZEF and i want: http://pastebin.com/Mk3BMX8P . Hope this helps ! thx